# Why when sending a POST jq request , on the server side I get a GET method?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

When sending a post request, I want to get a post on the server. Where is my problem?

This is not only happening with jq, I also tried to make a request using webclient.

```
$('#btnSaveSort').on('click', function () {
        var $sortableList = $("#sortable");
        var listElements = $sortableList.children();
        var jsonValues = "[";
        listElements.each(function (i, element) {
            if ($(element).data("index") != i)
                jsonValues += "{'key':'" + $(element).data("key") + "', 'position':'" + i + "'},";
        });
        jsonValues = jsonValues.slice(0, -1) + "]"; 
$.post("_f_Sorting.aspx", { val: jsonValues, mode: "updated", ip: 133 }, function () {});
 });
```

[This is the value of request type on the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rUIZ.png)

I expect the request type to be post, but the actual type is get

Comment: `jq` is not `jquery` (removed the tag)

Comment: What makes you think that it uses GET? Show some server-side code if needed.